# AutoMapper ForAllPropertyMaps with IValueConverter

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to replace an existing localization mechanism by using AutoMapper => ForAllPropertyMaps.

Database entities have properties marked with an **Localize** attribute, so the idea is that when mapping from Entity => Dto to intercept the entity property that is marked with the Localize attribute and translate it to the corresponding language before setting the value to the Dto property.

Below is my prof of concept, but in the case of a custom mapping like the one below:

```cs
CreateMap<Entities.Product, Dto.Product>().ForMember(a => a.OfferName, opt =>
{
    opt.PreCondition(m => m.ProductOffer != null);
    opt.MapFrom(a => a.ProductOffer.Name);
})
```

**I receive the *ProductOffer* as *SourceMember* instead of the *ProductOffer.Name*, and I didn't find any solution to identify the ***Name*** property value, so my question is, it possible to handle this types of scenarios in a generic way?**

```cs
public class ProfileBase : Profile
{
    public ProfileBase()
    {
        ForAllPropertyMaps(Condition, Configuration);
    }

    private static bool Condition(PropertyMap pm)
    {
        return pm.SourceMember != null &&
                    pm.SourceType == typeof(string) &&
                    pm.DestinationType == typeof(string) &&
                    pm.SourceMember.CustomAttributes.Any(a => a.AttributeType == typeof(LocalizedAttribute));
    }

    private static void Configuration(PropertyMap pm, IMemberConfigurationExpression opt)
    {
        opt.ConvertUsing(new LocalizedValueConverter());
    }
}

public class LocalizedValueConverter : IValueConverter<string, string>
{
    internal const string Language = "LANGUAGE";

    public string Convert(string sourceMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var language = context.Options.Items[Language]?.ToString();
        if (language == null)
        {
            return sourceMember;
        }

        return GetLocalizedValue(sourceMember, language); // Custom logic for translating the sourceMember value
    }
}

CreateMap<Entities.Product, Dto.Product>().ForMember(a => a.OfferName, opt =>
{
    opt.PreCondition(m => m.ProductOffer != null);
    opt.MapFrom(a => a.ProductOffer.Name);
})

namespace Dto
{
    public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ProductOfferId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string OfferName { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Entities
{            
    public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ProductOfferId { get; set; }
        [Localized]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Localized]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        
        public virtual ProductOffer ProductOffer { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProductOffer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Localized]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Localized]
        public string Description { get; set; }        
    }
}
```